# mysql: restore a value of a column from backup

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

I'm having trouble. Instead of launchin script

```
UPDATE table_name SET field=value WHERE id=12345
```

I launched

```
UPDATE table_name SET field=value
```

Database is backuped every day (with mysqldump). What is the simpliest way to restore the value of that column using the backup. obviously I cannot apply that backup dirrectly as database is continiously changed.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: if database is not committed, then rollback... :D

Comment: that was done a hour ago. How can I rollback?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would create a new table 'table_name2' identical to your 'table_name' but containing the data of your backup.

Then use this query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
table_name.field = (SELECT table_name2.field 
                    FROM table_name2 
                    WHERE table_name.id = table_name2.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

So you wiped out all values in the column and want to put all values back in the correct rows?

I would recommend unzipping the backup into a separate database and doing something like

```
    UPDATE live_db.table_name live 
INNER JOIN backup_db.table_name backup
        ON live.id = backup.id 
       SET live.field = backup.field
```

I would also recommend making a duplicate of your live site to try this on first ;)

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: i wanted to overwrite 3 items and had ended up overwriting 2200 in a table with 35.000 entries. With your statement the fix was done in no time - thanks a  lot!

Answer (score 2):

I would restore the backup of the table in another table called table_name_bck, then run the following sql.

```
UPDATE table_name_bck tb, table_name t
SET t.field = tb.field
WHERE tb.id = t.id
```

Of course try this in a test environment before to prevent worsening your situation.

Source: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the backup into another database and then make something like this (assuming that db1 is the production db and db2 is the temp database)

```
update db1.table set db1.field = db2.field where db1.id = db2.id
```